# Redux dispatch error asks for 1 and 0 arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Can someone explain how its possible to get an error like the following:

```
(alias) addDisplate(payload: Displate): {
    payload: Displate;
    type: "shopping cart/addDisplate";
}
import addDisplate
Calling this redux#ActionCreator with an argument will return a PayloadAction of type T with a payload of P

Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
createAction.d.ts(123, 6): An argument for 'payload' was not provided
```

My addDisplate reducer looks like the following:

```
addDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<Displate>) => {
  state.push(action.payload);
},
```

And I'm calling it from my frontend like so:

```
dispatch(addDisplate(displate));
```

Where the displate object is an interface called Displate and is defined in both the slice and in the component from where it is passed into the dispatch function.

It is exported from the cart-slice like so:

```
export const { addDisplate } = shoppingCartSlice.actions;
```

And imported into the component like so:

```
import { addDisplate } from "../features/shoppingCart/cart-slice";
```

If I don't provide an argument, I get an error. If I do provide an argument, I get an error

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? How is the `addDisplate` action exported, and how is it imported?

Comment: Yes just updated

Comment: Are you using  JetBrains IDE?

Comment: No Visual studio code

Comment: Then it should work. Can you try to create a reproduction of this? (Please mention me when you answer here)

Comment: I reproduced all the code, same error @phry

Comment: And it's not just that reducer, I tried adding another and calling it, same error

Comment: We have a slight miscommunication here: A "reproduction" means you create a GitHub repo, CodeSandbox or TypeScript playground that has the same problem and that you can publically link here so other people can try it out and see the problem.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't understand why. I installed @reduxjs/toolkit instead of @reduxjs/toolkit@next